# emailing diff output and email body

Tags: linux, email, unix, diff

I have the following code in my Bash script. How can I add body to the email?
 Example: Body: output

```
diff -q file1 file2 || diff file1 file2 | mail -s "subject" "email@email.com"
```

Comment: What version of `mail` do you have? Some, such as [s-nail](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html), support an `-a` option to attach a file.

Comment: sendmail-8.14.4-9.el6_8.1.x86_64

Comment: Really? That can't be what `rpm -qf /usr/bin/mail` says, `sendmail` doesn't provide that binary. (It's a MTA, not a MUA.) On CentOS you probably have `mailx` installed.

Comment: do rpm -qa | grep sendmail

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't matter for the `mail` command.

Comment: you are right.. its mailx-12.5-12.el7_0.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `mail` program that understand `-a` for attaching files, such as s-nail or mailx,

```
if ! diff -q file1 file2; then
    diff file1 file2 > something.diff
    echo 'body' | mail -s 'subject' -a something.diff 'email@email.com'
    rm -f something.diff
fi
```

You could use Bash's process substitution to avoid the temporary file

```
diff -q file1 file2 || echo 'body' | mail -s 'subject' -a <(diff file1 file2) 'email@email.com'
```

but the filename of the attachment will just be some random number.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
difference=` diff file1 file2 >/dev/null || diff file1 file2`
   if [ -n "$difference" ]; then
mail -s " subject " "address" <<EOF
     Body here

     $difference

      Body here

  EOF
 fi
```

Comment: If you're going to do it like that, then `{ echo 'Body here'; diff file1 file2; echo 'Body here'; } | mail -s ' subject ' 'address'` is better as it doesn't require loading the diff as a string into Bash. (Of course you can replace the `echo` with `cat <<HEREDOC`.)